# "rude or abusive" flag shows as "disputed" even though I retracted on time

Tags: support, disputed-flags

*Foreword:* I wouldn't have posted this question if I didn't feel something odd happened and here's the gist of it...

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53900478/how-can-run-construct-when-i-call-invoke-static-class-in-php-7-2) as "rude or abusive" when I saw their *"fuk down vote"* was added in an edit by the OP, who edited their question with it, maybe out of frustration for their question being downvoted; a comment to that effect they left in comments (also) appears to have been deleted; why, that I don't know.

**Edit notes:** I only flagged the **question** once, not twice. Please also note that I did not try and re-flag; my clicking on the "flag" button again was just to see what pops up (see further below), again only by curiosity.

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53900478/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53900478/3
- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53900478/4

which was edited out by another member. When I noticed the edit that removed the offensive comment by revisiting my flag area to check on its status and revisiting the question thereafter, I retracted my vote and I distinctively remember showing it as being "retracted" in my flag profile; **I know what I saw,** I am not making this up.

Plus, there were a few other comments that I flagged in the same question as being "It's unfriendly or unkind." that were marked as helfpul. The whole Karma in that whole question was just bad.

On top of that, when I clicked on "flag" in the question again (just by curiosity), it showed me: **You have already raised a high priority flag** under both **"spam"** *and* **"rude or abusive"**; I never flagged as "spam".

Can someone *please* explain to me what happened here? Because I am completely baffled.

Comment: If you raise a flag of a specifc type, you can't flag that post as that again. If you raise an R/A flag and retract it, that prevents you from raising any red flag (which means R/A and spam). If you flag as NAA, you can't flag as NAA or VLQ. Flagging as R/A or spam means you can still flag as NAA or VLQ, and NAA/VLQ means you can still flag as R/A or spam. Mod-flagging is separate from both of these. I'm personally not sure why it works like that (ask the devs), but that's just my observations from flagging.

Comment: @Zoe I only clicked on the flag button out of curiosity; I do that sometimes *lol!*. That's what I find odd, I didn't flag the question twice, only once. Maybe I should add that to my question. Edit: Which I did now.

Comment: I know, you specified that. But flagging as R/A or spam blocks re-flagging as spam and R/A, regardless of which of those you flagged as, should you retract it. Might apply if it's retracted too. The reason you can't flag as spam is because you flagged as R/A in the first place. Also, I made a mistake in my first comment; flagging as NAA doesn't exclude VLQ, and VLQ doesn't exclude NAA. What I said about R/A and spam does still apply: if you flag as either, it'll prevent you from flagging the post as spam or R/A independently of your original flag option.

Comment: @Zoe I appreciate your trying to help me understand how flags work, but about your *"The reason you can't flag as spam is because you flagged as R/A in the first place."* - I didn't try and re-flag after. I only clicked on the flag button again just to see what shows up in the popup, I think you might not understand what it is I meant about that.

Comment: I know. I'm sorry, but I probably didn't say this clearly: If you flag as R/A, that prevents you from re-flagging as R/A. However, it also prevents you from flagging as spam, regardless of whether you've flagged something as spam or not. Same with spam: if you flag something as spam, it prevents you from flagging as spam, but it also prevents you from flagging as R/A, even if you haven't flagged as spam. So even though you didn't flag as spam, you can't flag as spam because you flagged it as R/A. And yeah, the option is blocked; I'm not sure if you can actually flag it through the API though.

Comment: @Zoe No worries. Thing is though, and what I'd like to know is and what the question is partly about is, why it shows me *You have already raised a high priority flag under both "spam" and "rude or abusive"* which is what I mentioned in my question, as well as why my flag which I retracted on time showed me as being "retracted/self-removed" but then revisiting my flag area, now shows as "disputed". Those are the 2 things that baffle me.

Comment: When a mod clears rude/abusive/spam flags from a post it re-writes history and  makes every rude/absusive/spam flag on that post marked as disputed (whether it was originally helpful/declined)... I think - a side effect of this (and fairly sure it's come up before) - is that retracted flags of that type also get their status changed... it's a little confusing but at the end of the day since disputed means "nothing" and very few retract their flags - I think when it was last discussed it was considered such an edge case it wasn't that important to change in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: @JonClements Heh, yes it is (a tad) confusing Jon. Does the status change now puts an "X" on my record; as bad? If I retracted my flag, there shouldn't be an "X" on my record, or does it?

Comment: "Disputed" at the end of the day is the same as "retracted" - it doesn't count in anyway towards how your flag history is viewed. They're both as though you didn't bother flagging.

Comment: @JonClements Ok, thank you Jon.

Comment: So - end of the day - it would be nice if the system didn't over-write the flag resolution with "disputed" where it was marked as "retracted" - even if to just not gas light people in the very rare cases this happens... it's not going to affect anything regarding your flagging history in terms of any "bad mark" - it's frustrating in terms of confusion, but ultimately, just don't sweat it...

Comment: @JonClements Ok Jon, I won't (sweat it) and it would be nice as you say; that way it might avoid future posts like mine and avoid the confusion. Least I (now) know which "animal" I am dealing with *lol!* - Cheers and thanks again.